# Output sets of rows based on date ranges in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, `Data`, which contains rows of:

```
RecordTime, Data 1, Data 2, etc.
```

And another table, `DateRanges`, which contains rows of:

```
StartTime, EndTime
```

How do I write a query that generates a set of rows from `Data` for every row in `DateRanges` and output each set to a file (tab-separated) with a unique file name? Each set would be generated something like this:

```
Select * from Data
Where RecordTime Between StartTime (from Row 1, 2, etc.) and EndTime (from Row 1, 2, etc)
```

Comment: Please include db schema, sample data and expected output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: How many records are in the `DateRanges` table? You're likely going to have to iterate through each of those somehow. If I were doing it, I'd write a quick console app to loop through each DateRange record, calling a stored procedure which gets the appropriate data from the `Data` table. Then, that data can be exported to a spreadsheet/file in whatever format you deem necessary.

Comment: @BenM: The DateRanges table has 34 rows. The Data table has millions of rows.  I basically want to divide the records in Data based on the date ranges in DateRanges.  I can do this in C# using Entity Framework but I wanted to know how to do this purely in SQL.